# Let's do a Bike To Work Month contest!

Tags: discussion, contest, bike-to-work-month

[May is US National bike month](http://www.bikeleague.org/programs/bikemonth/), and is the chosen "bike month" for most northern hemisphere locations. This is when a lot of bike advocacy groups get together and do a lot of special bicycling promotions, such as Bike To Work Day, special outreach, etc...

Plus, we're over 2 years old and never did get around to doing an anniversary contest.

So how about it? Let's celebrate bike month with a contest! Maybe you could win a [spiffy t-shirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXALO.png) or [very nice water bottle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgurJ.png). Maybe a grand prize of a nice light set (a [review-winning](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/tail-light-review/) Cygolite HotShot tail light and some kind of awesome headlight?)

Here's some contests we could imitate:

- https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions
- https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/official-security-stack-exchange-anniversary-competition
- https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/webapps-second-anniversary-contest
- http://blog.superuser.com/2012/10/22/windows-8-challenge/

Comment: May is bike month for the fair weather crowd.  For the rest of us, bike month is January, February, ... , November, December.

Comment: @Kaz Perhaps I should be clearer that this has to do with bike advocacy groups promoting bicycling, not "when people that already ride get on a bike"...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a great idea! I particularly like combining an anniversary contest with bike to work month. Here are a few ideas I have:

- A **Stack Exchange bike to work contest**. A lot of companies do bike to work month contests to see who can bike the farthest (or most days) each week and during the whole month. If we could implement some sort of miles/trips tracker, we could have a prize for most miles biked and most days biked during bike to work month. The winner could get a little swag package with the Bikes.SE shirt, bottle, and stickers, and perhaps a nicer additional prize like a light. This part of the contest doesn't directly improve content on the site, but I believe it benefits promotion in a couple of ways: it gets people thinking about the site, coworkers and friends may find out about the site from seeing the contest participants getting buff, etc. Also, we like fun!
- We could do a **participation or tasks** aspect to the contest, like what we had on Super User for the [Windows 8 Challenge](http://win8challenge.com/). This could be something like weekly prizes during May for most questions asked/answered or rep gained.
- **Cleanup and site improvement tasks**, similar to some of the contests linked above. One possible downside is that with the new review tasks, there's a lot less cleanup to be done, which lowers the viability of a cleanup-based contest.
- **Promotion at local events** can help spread the word about the contest and the site in general. Many local bicycling advocacy groups have events during Bike to Work Month, and this is a great chance for us to spread the word about the site.

  - I'd specifically like to get a group together to volunteer at the May 12th **[Portland Sunday Parkways](http://www.portlandoregon.gov/transportation/46103)**. Groups can volunteer together to ["adopt" an intersection](http://www.portlandoregon.gov/transportation/article/434954) on the route, and will help riders and neighbors while also promoting their group. If we can get some people interested in this, we could set up a table at our adopted intersection, hand out swag and info about the site, etc. See the **[meta post for that event](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/804/attention-portlanders-lets-do-sunday-parkways)**.

Comment: I like the idea of a bike to work contest, but I think it's better to keep the contest focused within the site and for it to be based on things that SE staff could easily do with [queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/bicycles/queries) on site activity...

Comment: Promotion at local events would be awesome. Pretty sure Stack Exchange can send you a box of stickers, shirts and water bottles if you're planning to do that...

Comment: I really like the bike to work contest. Maybe we can get some SE-branded stickers specific to the event?